# Include backend name/ip in response headers in haproxy

Tags: haproxy

I am stuffing haproxy in front of 3 riak nodes with HTTP. I want the backend name and/or ip in the response headers. Something like:

```
X-Proxy-Backend: riak-1 10.0.0.1
```

or whatever.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: This works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43106728/843804

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the cookie function to add the serverid into your response. For example:

```
cookie SERVERID insert indirect
server webA 192.168.1.11:80 cookie A check
```

This will insert a cookie called `SERVERID=A` into the HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a header, you can use the [srv_id](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#7.3.3-srv_id) ACL like so:

```
rspadd X-Backend-Server:\ server1 if { srv_id 1 }
rspadd X-Backend-Server:\ server2 if { srv_id 2 }
```

You'll have to keep it in sync when you add/remove backend servers, but it works.