# HAProxy 1.5 - Show Server Name or IP Address in response while behind DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, haproxy, http-headers, ip-address, cookies

Basically exactly what the title is.  I have haproxy fronting a server, and infront of that a DNS to provide a human readable name.  I would like to setup haproxy to include either the responding server name or IP address in the response.  Originally, I used the method described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/215183/include-backend-name-ip-in-response-headers-in-haproxy).  While that works when going directly to the server, if I go to haproxy by the DNS, the cookie contains the DNS name.  Outside of the linked method, I've not found anything close to my use case.

Comment: Rather than looking at HAProxy, can’t you configure the backend server to add a header that identifies itself?

Comment: If by the backend server, you mean the service running on it, then yes, I could.  However, I was told to focus my efforts on using haproxy to do this universally instead of adding code to each backend service to add an identifying header.  Basically, haproxy is required.

Answer (score 0):

Use `srv_id` and add a header in the `backend` definition.  Like

```
http-response set-header X-Served-By 192.168.0.1 if { srv_id 1 }
http-response set-header X-Served-By 192.168.0.2 if { srv_id 2 }
```

etc.